# Render highcharts on the server, but the images are not clear

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

- I'm using the phantomjs + highcharts-convert.js solution to render the highcharts on a ubuntu server.
- Bug the exported images are not clear,especially the labels, title.
  [Sample Image](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1GDrkClp_5pyqImEiwj19mOqCB5Svepy47gd6ucb0alk/edit?usp=sharing)
- And as you see, the backgroud is black
- system info:

  - ubuntu 10.04 server 64bit

Comment: Do you have the same issue while using Highcharts exporting server?

Comment: thanks Pawel~
The contents in [Smaple Image](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1GDrkClp_5pyqImEiwj19mOqCB5Svepy47gd6ucb0alk/edit?usp=sharing)'s input json file(the value of -infile) is exactly  the same config on the demo server(http://export.highcharts.com/demo). This config works well on the demo server.

Comment: I think this issue may be caused by the low resolution of ubuntu server.

Comment: We changed the highcharts-convert script, now is a jpeg as default projected on a white page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
The feeling of 'unclear' is the illusion caused by the dark ground(jpg) or invisible ground(png).

Exporting png images and putting it on a white background would fix this.